# Freezing window when using multithread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a gui in java and I want to run inside my GUI when a button is pressed one executable. My code for running the executable is the following:

```
Process pr; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
new Thread(() -> {
try {
    Process proc = rt.exec("Release\\face.exe", null, new File("Release\\"));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
```

The executable is running when I am pressing the button however I detect a freezing in the executable behavior. I tried to add multithreading to check if that is the reason for freezing, however still I am experienced the same thing. What could be wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I tried to add the following lines for inputStreamReader inside my thread:

```
 new Thread(() -> {
 try {
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("face.exe", null, new File("Release\\"));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
      } catch (Exception e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }).start();
```

I got the message `InputStreamReader` cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Probably not enough code to answer... but you probably block the EDT somewhere.

Comment: How can I check if I have block the EDT? I am not really familiar with the EDT.

Comment: Give us the code of your event handler at least...

Comment: Just a shot into the blue: Move `Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime()`inside the runnable implementation. And you may want to add the complete button click handler code. Maybe it is blocking somewhere else ...

Comment: Didnt do the trick, I ll try to update my code in order to be clearer!

Comment: "How can I check if I have block the EDT?" - Mostly you realize it because the GUI freezes ...

Comment: In my case just the exe freezes, the gui runs  smoothly!

Comment: Ah - that changes everything! Then in your code all is fine. You'll have to debug `face.exe` in that case. If you have the impression it freezes. Is it a 3rd party application or do you have access to the code?

Comment: The executale run nice alone. I ve got access to the code, however it is a C++  code.

Comment: I suppose that if your run the exe directly it does not freeze?

Comment: Yup exactly! When I am running the exe works fine but inside the GUI it freezes.

Comment: What kind of GUI you have and what framework/environment does it run in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bowmore mentioned, your executable likely blocks because the output is not handled and "gets stuck" after a while as the executable cannot write more to its standard out (likely the console).

I usually use code like the following to run external commands from java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

StreamHandler outputHandler = new StreamHandler(in);
outputHandler.start();

StreamHandler errorHandler = new StreamHandler(err);
errorHandler.start();
```

where StreamHandler is defined as follows:

```
class StreamHandler extends Thread {
        private final BufferedReader in;
        private final JTextArea[] textArea;

        public StreamHandler(final BufferedReader in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String line = null;
                while ((line = this.in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.info("StreamHandler got interrupted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Naturally, the stream handler could be more sophisticated, e.g. write errors to System.err instead of System.out, or to write to a JTextArea, or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don not read the InputStreams for this process object, it is possible that it's stuck because the stream's buffer is full, causing the exe to block on the write to stdout.

Comment: Wow that was it. Inside the executable I wrote things in a file, when I comment out this line the executable worked fine. However this is crucial for me, to write all the things to file, how can I overcome this burden?

Comment: Well, the burden now lies on your java code to do something with the output. You could write it to your Java program's stdout, or to a file.

Comment: In fact the executable open a camera and tracks some points from the face, and then stores them real time in a file, how is it possible to parse those points from executable to java?

Comment: java.lang.Process#getInputStream gives you an `InputStream`, which you should read to get all the exe's output to stdout. If you want to parse this data immediately, that is certainly possible.

Comment: is it possible to send me an example of how to output my arrays from c++ code in order to get it using the getInputStream?